# Add Day Before Cut Off Time To jquery.ui.datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**What I Have**

In jquery.ui.datepicker I have changed the value minDate to +1 so todays date or any historical date cannot be selected.
All good so far.....However.....

**What I Want**

I want to stop anyone selecting tomorrows date after 8pm today, so, after 8pm tomorrows date should no longer be available for selection.
I cannot see an option to do this in the default values or any of the examples on the datePicker website.

**What is the best or easiest way I can achieve this?**

Thanks in advance of a hopefully good suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, **jQuery DatePicke**r hasn't yet provided the functionality to support time(i guess) we need to do this in manual way.

You can use `beforeShow` [options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) of jQuery DatePicker; which is called upon the datePicker UI display every time you click on *DatePicker input field*.

So, Inside `beforeShow` you can calculate the current time and manipulate the minDate as required ,

```
beforeShow : function(){
        var dateTime = new Date();
        var hour = dateTime.getHours();
        //If Hour is greater or equals to 8PM
        if(hour  >= 20){
            //Disable all past days including tomorrow and today
            $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" );
        }
    }
```

### Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/314/).

**P.S**

1. I haven't tried this yet but you should look into this
   [DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) plugin
   if you want a more subtle approach

Comment: Hi Runcorn, thank you so much for that, it works perfectly :-)